# how to send image and text and install app link in share to other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, share, intentfilter

I am very new to this topic how to share my app along with image and text,play store link,my images and text getting from server and image should be not visible after sharing content ,please any one help me how to share this content to other apps like whats app,twitter and more ....

here below my code

```
 File filePath = getFileStreamPath("news_image");
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(filePath));
            shareIntent.setType("image/png");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Here is my IMAGE");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share IMAGE Using..."))
```

Comment: Where is your code? have you tried anything?

Comment: may be you are searching for picasso .

Comment: @chanti u want to share image using share intent ??

Comment: yes image and text along with app playstore url

Comment: i post my code have a look once above@RRR

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the advice from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html).

Snippet from the page:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: my image and text was not sharing @Selcuk Cihan